# Sending email based on Case criteria

Tags: email, workflow

I wanted to create a workflow rule from a reports I have, is it possible at all?
for example:
I will have a report with companies with following case -
"All expired certificate without activities by 30 or 60 days"
So I would like to send email to these companies automatically (using Workflow rules)or at least manually (with less clicks) but to all companies email at the same time. Is this possible? let me know if you need more details on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this with a custom checkbox or a text field which upon checking/filling will fire a [workflow rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_wf.htm&type=5&language=en_US) with [email alert](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_wfalerts.htm&type=0). More flexible would be to use trigger instead of workflow and populate the field with developerName of the email template to be sent.

Then just simply export and import data from the report with the checkbox true/text field populated.

preparation

1. new checkbox field
2. new workflow to fire every time the checkbox = true
3. email alert as action of this workflow
4. email template as the template which will be sent

execution

1. export companies id with the new checkbox
2. update the checkbox in excel to true
3. import back via data wizard or data loader

Comment: Thank you , but honestly, I'm pretty new to SF, can you tell me more in details if you can please? that would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: i updated the answer along with some documentation

Comment: Thank you! I will try it.